# General form of elements in the vector lattice (Riesz Space) generated by a vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, lattice-orders, vector-lattices, banach-lattices

Can any one tell me how the elements of the set $A^{∧∨}$ will look like? I believe they are of the following form:
$∨^m_i∧^{m_i}_{k_i} x_{i,{k_i}}$ where $x_{i,{k_i}}$ is in $A$. But in this case I'm unable to show that their union $(∨^m_i∧^{m_i}_{k_i} x_{i,{k_i}})$ ∨ $(∨^n_j∧^{n_j}_{l_j} y_{j,{l_l}})$ is in $A^{∧∨}$. Or, for negative scalar $\alpha$, how to show that $\alpha (∨^m_i∧^{m_i}_{k_i} x_{i,{k_i}})$ is in $A^{∧∨}$? [image]

Comment: To show that $A^{\wedge\vee}$ is closed under joins ($\vee$) is immediate; what is not immediate is that it is closed under meets ($\wedge$); but that can be proved using $A^{\vee\wedge}=A^{\wedge\vee}$, which follows from distributivity. About the scalars, I don't know...

Comment: About the negative scalar, there are such properties as $$-(x\vee y)=-x\wedge -y,\text{ and } -(x\wedge y)=-x\vee -y,$$ right? If so, using $-\alpha>0$ if $\alpha<0$, then you can get $$\alpha(x\vee y)=\alpha x\wedge\alpha y,$$ and then use the fact that $A^{\vee\wedge}$ is closed under the lattice operations.

Comment: @amrsa right but I'm rather interested in the general form of the elements because I want to construct linear order preserving maps on $A^{∧∨}$

Comment: Well, you've certainly got it. I got the same shape as you did for the elements of $A^{\wedge\vee}$, and I think there is not much to get wrong with that...